# How can I invoke a Qt dialog from a secondary thread in PyQt and wait for result?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a secondary python thread that is performing a few operations. Through these operations, the user must be inquired if the process is allowed to continue.

I obviously can't invoke the dialog directly because that would be a secondary thread invoking GUI code, so I must post an event, but if I do so, I will just invoke the dialog. I need the result (Ok/Cancel) as well. In practice, from the secondary thread I must post an event on the main thread event queue, and wait until that event has been processed and the result returned.

This sounds very awkward to do, and I am sure there's already some code in Qt to do so, but I can't find it. Remember I am not using QThread, I am using python threads.

Comment: Use signals to transmit information from the GUI thread to any other thread and vice versa. signals are thread-safe

Comment: @eyllanesc not at all. if I use python threads, thread affinity is not defined and  connect cannot perform a queued connection. You end up with a direct connection and that implies that whatever code is called when you emit the signal is executed in the secondary thread. Regardless, if I use a signal I don't get a result back anyway.

Comment: You have to use `Qt::QueuedConnection`, here it does not matter if it is `QThread` or not, since the end `QThread` is just a thread handle. Another option is to use `QMetaObject`, that is, create an `@pyqtSlot` that performs the operation you want, for this you must pass the view to the GUI (pass it but not use any function) and then use `QMetaObject::InvokedMethod(...)`

Comment: Even if I do so, how can I get the result back?

Comment: You have to avoid the forward process, maybe you can use a QEventLoop, and connect the reception signal to the quit() method, then when the eventloop signal arrives, it will be finished. Although that is going to be tedious, I would modify your design and implement a state machine, where each task is a thread, so if task1 ends then I send a signal and then I make the request to the user and start another thread with the remaining task.